# Generating a subgroup with two permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups

I have what appears to be a simple question but I do not know if my method is correct.  I have to find what the subgroup of $S_5$ generated by $(123)$ and $(12345)$ is.

So I have worked out that the product of the above permutations is $(52134)$ so now do I compute the 5th power of the product I calculated? Then somehow find out what subgroup that is?

Comment: Observe that *in fact* you'll get a subgroup of $\;A_5\;$ ...

Comment: Bhaskar Vashishth 's answer in the duplicate post shows that your subgroup is $A_5$.

Answer (score 1):

Since your subgroup will be of $\;A_5\;$ and this is a simple group, you are somehow restricted in your choices. For example, its index can't be less than $\;4\;$ as then the regular action would provide a contradiction.

But then you already have elements of order $\;3,\,5\;$ so at least you have a subgroup of order $\;15\;$...and this subgroup's index is already four, which is impossible, so **it must be** the subgroup is the whole $\;A_5\;$

Comment: Okay, so by that logic would the subgroup generated by say $ (12)$ and $(12345)$ be $A_4$

Comment: @user That'd be a very special "logic" since $\;(12)\notin A_4\;$ ...

Comment: Thanks for the sarcasm, my mistake, $A_n$ is generated by three cycles, but $(1 2)$ and $(12345)$ do not produce three cycles and when multiplied and squared they produce the elements of $S_4$. Correct?